# strtotime returns strange characters

Tags: wordpress

I want to show date of events created via custom post type and ACF in Wordpress. I try to figure out why this:

```
<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR'); echo strftime('%d %h %Y', strtotime(get_field('date_de_levenement'))); ?>
```

returns strange characters like this:

```
04 ao�t 2014
```

(Here the *04 ao�t 2014* should be *04 août 2014*

Comment: What encoding do you have set on the page?

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I'll post my solution as soon as the 8 hours restriction is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this!

```
utf8_encode
```

So I get

```
<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR'); define("CHARSET", "utf-8"); echo utf8_encode (strftime('%d %h %Y', strtotime(get_field('date_de_levenement')))); ?>
```